# Is it possible to limit a blockchain to a single token/contract?

Tags: blockchain

I want to create blockchain that will have only my token in that chain(eg: a fork on ethereum).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could just have your node reject transactions that are to any contracts other than the one you want to allow. If you want anyone to be able to be a node producer, you'll have to modify the software to reject blocks that contain transactions to any other contracts.

Comment: But how can I enforce this rejection on all nodes? I can control my node, but not other people's.

Comment: Like I said above, if you plan on this being a public network where anyone can be a block producer, then you'll have to modify the client code to reject blocks with transactions that create contracts after you create yours. You'll then have to have all the nodes run that software